# About MySQL Table permission remove failure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable

My MySQL database version is 5.6.35 and I use InnoDB.

I want to remove the Delete and Drop Table permissions of the user U1 from the table T1 in the db1 database.
The operating instructions are as follows:

```
Revoke delete,drop on db1.T1 from U1;
```

No error message appeared after execution.

But after execution, the user U1 can still use the DELETE command to delete the data row in the data table T1.
You can also use the DROP TABLE command to delete the data table T1.

Thanks for replying.